# How do i set password to zip file in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, zip, ssms, etl

I have compressed file by 7-zip using Execute Process Task in SSIS. Now i have to set password to zip file How can i achieve that ?

[image: Execute Process Task process tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is a ssis issue. You have to take a look at [7zip command line user guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm) and check if this option is provided.

Also there are other useful links:

- https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

**Update 1**

I think this is the link you are looking for

- https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/password.htm

Comment: Thank you very much @Hadi I am able to set password for file by specifying Arguments as **a "data.zip"  -psecret "data.xls"** Is there anyway to set password to open zip file itself

Comment: @vinothkumar password is needed when extracting files from archive not openning it. And the command is found in the link i provided

Comment: Yeah i just opened not extracted it's working perfectly Thank you very much for your time :)