# SSIS Extraction Approach

Tags: ssis, etl, unzip, 7zip, extract

I have to do extraction of zipped file using SSIS, I could think of two available option 7zip or Script Task using 
`System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()` function.

I need a suggestion which is more efficient approach?

Any other more efficient approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both methods since they can both solve your issue. But if I was asked to solve a similar issue I will use 7Zip since it is a seperate third party product and [it is improved continuously](https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) and may have additional functionalities, while `System.IO.Compression` assembly is a part of a larger framework (.Net Framework) and its improvement are less frequent.

You can use 7zip from an Execute Process Task by passing command line arguments:

- [Unzip .tar.gz files in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309762/unzip-tar-gz-files-in-ssis/48310289#48310289)
- [Zip a folder using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416229/zip-a-folder-using-ssis/44418705#44418705)
- [How do i set password to zip file in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362161/how-do-i-set-password-to-zip-file-in-ssis/43363142#43363142)

Comment: @Toshniwal11 please feel free to accept the answer by [clicking on the Mark located on the left side of the answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)